Identifying Solana Account Types Programmatically: Account, Program Account, Token Account, Vote Account, and More
In Solana, how can I programmatically determine the account type of a specific Solana address, such as whether it is an account, program account, token account, vote account, or any other account type?

Just curious to know the use case for this?

The account "type" is defined by owner in Solana, which is a program (an on-chain contract) in particular.
Every account has got some owner (https://solanacookbook.com/core-concepts/accounts.html#facts) so there is no generic "Account type". The type is defined by the program id.

Program account, managing executable data, is account owned most probably by BPFLoaderUpgradeab1e11111111111111111111111 but one of the program loaders, see What's the difference between the different program loaders?
Token related accounts is most probably program owned by TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA (but there is Token-2022 https://spl.solana.com/token-2022, for NFT there are different ones https://solana.com/developers/nfts). For differentiating the token account type (like differentiate of being a mint or a token) you will need to "parse" data of the account. Account data structure is not standardized and every program may use different data layout.
Vote account is owned by program id Vote111111111111111111111111111111111111111, see others at doc at https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/v1.18.11/docs/src/runtime/programs.md?plain=1#L52


thanks，This answer has been of great help to me
